# addons.manager ERROR startup failed:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am getting this below error, is this really a error or just a warning message that I can ignore, please help. Also my test code runs well but opening another blank window in browser.

I am using selenium 3.4.0 Firefox browser 47.0.2 geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64
also need know the compatibility of versions of browser and selenium

Below is the testcode:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Roma\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String vURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
driver.navigate().to(vURL);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='day']")).sendKeys("9");
driver.quit();
```

Console Error :

```
1507800976077   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1507800976669   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < AddonManagerInternal.validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:665 < AddonManagerInternal.startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:832 < this.AddonManagerPrivate.startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:2773 < amManager.prototype.observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:57
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1639: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
1507800977720   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 51248
JavaScript error: undefined, line 492: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2484: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Oct 12, 2017 3:06:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update browser and geckoDriver , I will suggest use ff50 and 51 with geckodriver version 17 or 18.

also comment this line `driver = new FirefoxDriver()` no need to instantiate twice

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Roma\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
//driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String vURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
driver.navigate().to(vURL);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='day']")).sendKeys("9");
driver.quit()
```

;

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help, I have updated FF to 56.0 (64-bit) and geckodriver to geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64 but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

In general, each **`GeckoDriver`** release supports each version of **`Mozilla Firefox`** releases (beginning with Firefox 48) where the property **`"marionette"`** needs to be set to **`true`** (either by **default** or through **configuration**)

If you are working with the legacy **`Firefox`** releases (till **Firefox 47.x**) **`GeckoDriver`** still works but you have to explicitly set the property **`"marionette"`** to **`false`**

Regarding the compatibility of **`GeckoDriver`**, **`Selenium`** and **`Mozilla Releases`**:

1. **`GeckoDriver`** `Release Notes` clearly states all the major/minor **`New Feature Addition`**, **`Enhancements`**,**`Bug Fixes`** and **`Download Location`** separately in this [**link**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
2. **`Selenium`** `Release Notes` clearly states all the major/minor **`New Feature Addition`**, **`Enhancements`**,**`Bug Fixes`** and **`Download Location`** separately in this [**link**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases)

---

> **Selenium Dependencies**:
>
> **`Selenium 3.4.0`** now recommends **`Geckodriver v0.16.0`** strongly.
>
> **`Selenium 3.3.1`** better supports **`Geckodriver v0.15.0`**.

---

> **GeckoDriver Dependencies**:
>
> **`geckodriver v0.18.0`** now recommends **`Firefox 53 and greater`**
>
> **`geckodriver v0.16.0`** is only compatible with **`Selenium 3.4 and greater`**.